# Unable to use sjPlot's plot_model function — two errors

Tags: r, package, namespaces, sjplot

I have a script that usually allows me to plot Odds Ratios with `plot_model`. However, when I tried to run it today, I got two errors.

When using `plot_model` on a model that runs, RStudio told me the function could not be found.

I ensured sjPlot was installed and loaded and then tried using `sjPlot::plot_model...` to make sure R looked in the right package, but I got another error: `object ‘standard_error_robust’ is not exported by 'namespace:parameters'`

1. **What might cause that error?**
2. **How might I solve the problem to get the `plot_model` function working again?**

Comment: Try with updating your packages. See this closed Github issue for more info: https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/866

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stefan [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74997671/unable-to-use-sjplots-plot-model-function-two-errors?noredirect=1#comment132348469_74997671) the answer for me on a GitHub page.

I'm pasting the steps that I used from that page below:

1. Restart R (or RStudio, or whatever you're using)
2. If RStudio, also press Shift + F10
3. Run `easystats::install_latest()`
4. Run `install.packages(c("sjstats", "sjPlot"))`

Answer (score 0):

For this, I tried everything but ultimately one thing worked for me:

I had to update all the libraries in R console, it worked for me

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE)
```